# CoffeeScript: assigning multiple properties to an initialised object

Tags: coffeescript

```
w = {c: true}
w =
  a: 4
  b: true
console.log w
```

I expect the result `w` to be {a: 4, b: true, c: true}, but I get {a: 4, b: true}.
How can I do multiple assignments to object properties without loosing already set properties?

Comment: The answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/929776/306084) might prove useful, as what you're doing is merging properties in to the initial object.

Answer (score 1):

[CoffeeScript: assigning multiple properties to an initialised object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25893157/coffeesscript-asigning-multiple-properties-to-an-initialised-object#comment40525299_25893157) has been the best answer so far.

But if you only want to add a few properties to an object you can just do:

```
w = {c: true}
w.a = 4
w['b'] = true  # alternative notation
```

Also, this question is more about JavaScript than CoffeeScript.

Comment: That's obviuous I know ... but not very pretty, I am looking for a short notation, in real life w is an object with a long name and I have many properties to add.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done directly. I believe, you need to iterate:

```
w = {c: true}
temp =
  a: 4
  b: true
w[k] = v for k,v of temp
console.log w
```

Comment: hmm... this does the assigment of each property twice

Comment: True, but solution from @Yuri does it same way - look at the transpiled code.

Comment: Most efficient way seems to be from @Tomasz Zieliński - not very pretty though.

Answer (score 0):

```
w = {c: true}
w[i] = v for i,v of {
  a: 4
  b: true
}
console.log w
```