# combine json object jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
[{"First Name":"qwe","member":"complainant"},{"Last Name":"qwee","member":"scienceclub"},{"Middle Name":"wqe","member":"complainant"}]
```

I have only this json above how can i combine/flatten/merge them so that i can get the resulting json like

```
[{"First Name":"qwe","Last Name":"qwe","Middle Name":"wqe","member":"scienceclub"}]
```

I search for a function in jquery but all i see are the ones with `2 object`.

Any suggestion is appreciated

`UPDATE`

I dont separate json array it is just one with arrays inside is it possible to merge the array inside of `[]`?

Comment: And which value do you expect to pick up for `member` property? Your original array has different value for member, the second only have one with one value. What's the logic behind keeping `scienceclub` over the rest?

Comment: Are you looking for $.extend ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929776/merging-associative-arrays-javascript

Comment: @gillesc they will be the same so anywhere will do

Comment: @BalintDomokos as you can see i only have i object i just want it to look like the illutrated out put the example you gave is a bit different

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your array like this

```
var arr = [{"First Name":"qwe","member":"complainant"},{"Last Name":"qwee","member":"scienceclub"},{"Middle Name":"wqe","member":"complainant"}];
```

use `extend` this way to get your job done

```
var obj1 = arr[0];
$.extend(obj1, arr[2]);
$.extend(obj1, arr[1]);
```

The result will be in `obj1` as

> {"Last Name":"qwee", "Middle Name":"wqe", "Last Name":"qwee", "member":"scienceclub"}

Comment: I have only one object i dont have 3 this is result of getting all input text from a table tr so i cant really separate them.

Comment: Check it out! might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = [{
  "First Name": "qwe",
  "member": "complainant"
}, {
  "Last Name": "qwee",
  "member": "scienceclub"
}, {
  "Middle Name": "wqe",
  "member": "complainant"
}];
alert(JSON.stringify(
  $.extend.apply(null, a)
  , null, '\t'
));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
arr = [{"First Name":"qwe","member":"complainant"},{"Last     Name":"qwee","member":"scienceclub"},{"Middle Name":"wqe","member":"complainant"}]
arr.splice(0, 0, {})
result = $.extend.apply(this, arr)
```

You still need to deal with multiple keys, this will use the last one. The splice is needed to avoid changing the first object of the array.