# What is the purpose of using Object.create()?

Tags: javascript

```
this.options = Object.assign(Object.create(this.defaultOptions), options);
```

I understand what this code is doing, but what is the purpose of `Object.create()`? The only benefit I can think of is that you can reference `defaultOptions` even if you override them. But I can't think of a good reason why that would be useful for 99% of the time.

Comment: it's a useful tool for a particular job ... if you don't have a nail, I guess you wouldn't know what a hammer is for

Answer (score 2):

Using `Object.create` sets the prototype of `this.options`. It allows you to shadow the properties on `defaultOptions` on the `options` property, *and* lets you revert to the `defaultOptions` when needed. For example:

```js
const options = { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' };
class Something {
  constructor() {
    this.defaultOptions = options; // only a reference
    this.options = Object.assign(Object.create(this.defaultOptions), options);
  }
}
const inst = new Something();
// Change 'foo':
inst.options.foo = 'foo2';
console.log(inst.options.foo);
// Reset 'foo' to default:
delete inst.options.foo;
console.log(inst.options.foo);
// Assign another custom value to 'foo':
inst.options.foo = 'foofoo';
console.log(inst.options.foo);
```

This same sort of behavior would not be possible without `Object.create` - once the object was instantiated, if any `option` was overwritten, the only way to get the default option would be to have a reference to the default option, which couldn't necessarily be relied on:

```js
const options = { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' };
class Something {
  constructor(constrOptions) {
    this.defaultOptions = options; // only a reference
    this.options = Object.assign({}, this.defaultOptions, constrOptions);
  }
}
const inst = new Something();
// Change 'foo':
inst.options.foo = 'foo2';
console.log(inst.options.foo);


// Reset 'foo' to default...??
delete inst.options.foo;
// Doesn't work:
console.log(inst.options.foo);


// Assign another custom value to 'foo':
inst.options.foo = 'foofoo';
console.log(inst.options.foo);
```

Comment: In what situations would you want to revert back to default?

Comment: For example, a user interface where each option has a "Reset to default" button

Answer (score 0):

`Object.create()` creates the new object from passes object. I am not sure about your concern over here. But you can surely visit MDN for more details:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

https://medium.com/@tkssharma/objects-in-javascript-object-assign-deep-copy-64106c9aefab

[Using Object.assign and Object.create for inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33692912/using-object-assign-and-object-create-for-inheritance)