# Firebase: "TypeError: currentUser.updateProfile is not a function" after merging firebase user with another object

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, next.js

I'm trying to update af user's profile with [`updateProfile()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users?authuser=1#update_a_users_profile)

When I call the function exactly as the example from the [link above](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users?authuser=1#update_a_users_profile), it throws the `TypeError: currentUser.updateProfile is not a function`. I tried to `console.log()` the user and weirdly it does not show the `updateProfile()` function.

I'm using the user retrieved from [`auth.onAuthStateChanged()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users?authuser=1#get_the_currently_signed-in_user). I then uses Firebase firestore where I store other user info. I merges that user object with the data retrieved from firestore with:

`const mergedUser = Object.assign({}, user, doc.data())`

I pass `mergedUser` to a useState() `currentUser` that is passed to my context provider value.

Everything else works, but the functions that is supposed to be on the userobject is not present after the Object.assign(). How could merge the user object so I can access all userdata AND the firebase user functions, such as [`updateProfile()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users?authuser=1#update_a_users_profile)

Thank you in advance!

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "planom",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^8.2.7",
    "next": "10.0.6",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.32.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.assign` copies all enumerable properties (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). However, this doesn't include non-enumerable properties (like prototype methods).

I can think of a few different solutions:

#### Use `firebase.auth().currentUser`

`firebase.auth().currentUser` is already available in the global scope, so you could access the methods that way

#### Restructure your state

Instead of trying to combine `user` and `doc.data()`, make them different properties of a new object. Eg:

```
{
  user: user,
  userData: doc.data()
}
```

*(The downside here is that you're still trying to store a complex object with methods in state -- not ideal if relying on a state that gets rehydrated, for example)*

#### Use Object.create? Maybe?

Personally, I wouldn't mess around with this system if I were you, as the first two are much simpler and more reliable if the underlying API changes, but you could try to use `Object.create` and then `Object.assign` to create an object that *did* have the original methods available. See this answer: [Using Object.assign and Object.create for inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33692912/using-object-assign-and-object-create-for-inheritance)

Comment: Ahh okay. I will definitely look into those and see what works best. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your link to your js-file bellow ALL other firebase script imports.
Your error is quite common if you link them in the wrong order, also don't forget to defer the script tag if you link to your script in your header.

```
<script src="myJS.js" defer></script>
```

Defer makes sure that the js document is read after the HTML, and if you copied your firebase js-imports, they're also deferred.

Comment: I'm using next.js so I haven't set anything like that up. I don't think that's the way you (normally) use next.js

Comment: Thank you though :)