# How does {...object, property: value} work with spread syntax?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

When reviewing the ES6 docs, I noted that it is recommended to use the spread syntax over the more verbose `Object.assign()` method. But, I am a bit confused as to how this is being accomplished.

Is `object` in this case being broken down to `key: value` pairs, after which the property on the right of the comma is either added or overwritten, and finally being reassembled?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/41615569/7404943

Comment: that's it in a nutshell

Comment: You were surely not reading *ES6* docs - object spread is still an experimental proposal. What were you reading? Please link it.

Answer (score 4):

> Is object in this case being broken down to key: value pairs, after which the property on the right of the comma is either added or overwritten, and finally being reassembled?

The key-value pairs of the original object `object` are actually being used in combination (merging) with the new object which has an extra property `var2`( they are getting combined to `newObject`).

You can think of it as `object` is becoming a subset of `newObject` in the place where the spread syntax in being used, while properties with same key are being overridden.

Check the below example:

```js
const object = { txt: 'Test' };
const newObject = {...object, var2: 'aa' };

// logs Object {txt: "Test", var2: "aa"}
console.log(newObject);

const object2 = { txt: 'Test' };
const newObject2 = {...object, txt: 'Test2', var2: 'aa' };

// Object {txt: "Test2", var2: "aa"}
console.log(newObject2);

// merging all objects to a new object
var object3 = {first: 'Hello', second: 'World'};
var newObject3 = {...object, anotherVar: 'stack', ...object2, ...object3};

// Object {txt: "Test", anotherVar: "stack", first: "Hello", second: "World"}
console.log(newObject3);
```