# Object is not extensible error when creating new attribute for array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that needs to extend a javascript array, including a new attribute called `selected`:

```
export const initSelect = (data) => {

    let newData = data.concat();
    newData.map((item) => {
        item.selected = false;
    })

    return newData;
}
```

`data` is a ReactJS state value (comes from `this.state.data` when calling the function), but this didn't seem to be a problem as `newData` is a new copy of `data` array...

I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot add property selected, object is not extensible
```

Comment: In order to really understand this error this here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_define_property_object_not_extensible might help.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You probably need to copy the objects:

```
export const initSelect = (data) => {
 return data.map((item) => ({
     ...item,
     selected: false       
 }));
}
```

Comment: @Jonasw the op is misusing concat and map. I think your solution should not be misusing them also.

Comment: Will the returned object a copy of `data` ? I will use the return to set the ReactJS object state....

Comment: Works!!!! I did not get this error locally but in the deployed version of my app, anyone here knows why this is happening ?

Answer (score 47):

You can not extend `item` with `selected` property, and your array is just a shallow copy.

If you want to be able to extend, you will have to do a deep copy of your array. It may be enough with:

```
let newData = data.map((item) => 
    Object.assign({}, item, {selected:false})
)
```

Comment: I see the same error with Object.assign approach. I manage to solve it using @Jonas anwer.

Comment: Then probably you are doing something wrong @RocíoGarcíaLuque, as Jonas' solution and mine are equivalent according to my understandings of https://stackoverflow.com/a/50558264/2832398

Comment: You are totally right. I cannot remember the situation, but probably yes, I was doing something wrong. Your solution is perfectly valid :+1:

Answer (score 18):

```
data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: That seems like some unnecessary "stringifycation". There could also be objects in `data` that could not be stringified and therefor destroy the original data.

Comment: for my "unpushable" array, this was perfect

Comment: you can rely on lodash.deepClone(data) to avoid nested data loss

Answer (score 13):

```js
const newObj = Object.assign({selected: false}, data);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Please, keep in mind that this code afaik is not equivalent. If data already contains selected: true for example, the new object will end up with selected: true.