# TypeError while adding property to custom array data type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was introducing typescript to my current code. The size of the codebase is quite huge so started from the basic types. I have built custom data types to handle UI in a better way.

Following is the code for `CustomArray` which I have.

```
/**
 Author - Harkirat Saluja
 Git - https://bitbucket.org/salujaharkirat/
 **/

declare global {
  interface Array<T>{
    filterBy(o: T): Array<T>,
    sortAscBy(o: T): Array<T>,
    sortDescBy(o: T): Array<T>
  }
}


class CustomArray {
  static init (value = []) {
    if (!value) {
      value = [];
    }
    if (!(value instanceof Array)) {
      value = [value];
    }

    value.filterBy = function (property) {
      return !property ? this : this.filter(item => item[property]);
    };

    value.sortAscBy = function (property) {
      return !property ? this : this.sort((a, b) => a[property] - b[property]);
    };

    value.sortDescBy = function (property) {
      return !property ? this : this.sort((a, b) => b[property] - a[property]);
    };

    return arrayValue;
  }
}

export default CustomArray;
```

In production I am getting error `TypeError: Cannot add property to a non extensible object`.

As per the mozilla [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_define_property_object_not_extensible), if we add `Object.preventExtensions` it should show me this error but I am not using that anywhere.

I was debugging it a bit and following code works fine:-

```
/**
 Author - Harkirat Saluja
 Git - https://bitbucket.org/salujaharkirat/
 **/

declare global {
  interface Array<T>{
    filterBy(o: T): Array<T>,
    sortAscBy(o: T): Array<T>,
    sortDescBy(o: T): Array<T>
  }
}


class CustomArray {
  static init (value = []) {
    if (!value) {
      value = [];
    }
    if (!(value instanceof Array)) {
      value = [value];
    }

    const arrayValue = [...value]; //Making a new copy works
    arrayValue.filterBy = function (property) {
      return !property ? this : this.filter(item => item[property]);
    };

    arrayValue.sortAscBy = function (property) {
      return !property ? this : this.sort((a, b) => a[property] - b[property]);
    };

    arrayValue.sortDescBy = function (property) {
      return !property ? this : this.sort((a, b) => b[property] - a[property]);
    };

    return arrayValue;
  }
}

export default CustomArray;
```

Though the error is fixed, it will really me if someone is able to help me understand why I am facing this issue?

Comment: Why aren't you using `CustomArray  extends Array`?

Comment: Can u please share the code? It will really help me a lot :) @adiga

Comment: That's an unrelated suggestion. `CustomArray extends Array` will allow the instances `CustomArray` access all the functionalities of Array. That's not your issue here. Are you using react or something similar where the `value` parameter being passed is immutable? Like this: [Object is not extensible error when creating new attribute for array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798885)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you passed an array which is [not-extensible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions). When you add a property `value.filterBy`, it will throw an error.

Instead of directly adding a property to every array, you could make `CustomArray` inherit from `Array`. This way, it will have all the functionalities of Array and the additional methods will be on `CustomArray.prototype` instead of directly on each array instances

Since you can get non-Array value as parameter, you could do `[].concat(value)` to always get an array.

```js
const convert = v => [].concat(v)

console.log( convert(1) )
console.log( convert([1, 2]) )
```

Call the [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array) constructor using `super` and spreading the contents of the array.

```js
class CustomArray extends Array {
  constructor(value = []) {
    super(...[].concat(value))
  }

  filterBy(property) {
    return !property ? this : this.filter(item => item[property]);
  }

  sortAscBy(property) {
    return !property ? this : this.sort((a, b) => a[property] - b[property]);
  }

  sortDescBy(property) {
    return !property ? this : this.sort((a, b) => b[property] - a[property]);
  }
}

const a1 = new CustomArray([{ age: 10 }, { age: 5 }])
console.log(a1.sortAscBy('age'))

const a2 = new CustomArray(["a", "bbb", "", "cc"])
console.log(JSON.stringify( a2 ))
console.log(JSON.stringify( a2.sortDescBy('length') ))
console.log(JSON.stringify( a2.filterBy('length') )) 
// ^ empty string is removed because item[property] returns 0 and 0 is falsy

const a3 = new CustomArray({ key: "value" }) // non-array item
console.log(a3)

const a4 = new CustomArray() // default empty array
console.log(a4)
```