# Cannot add property effectTag, object is not extensible

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-dom

On loading react application it is rendering perfect but only for a few sec. after that it shows this error. unable to debug this. Showing error in node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21959
Can anyne help me with this?[image]

Comment: Can you provide the full error log you are getting?

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya, added image

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798885/object-is-not-extensible-error-when-creating-new-attribute-for-array-of-objects

Comment: You need to pass some example, what have you tried and what have you added, you need to first debug where it happens, people here don't know your project so if you want to help you first help us ;)

Answer (score -2):

don't manipulate data directly first make copy then modify it