# Redux: Reduced - How to avoid object is not extensible error during the recursion on nested array?

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, reducers

I have the following array of objects with nested objects:

```
[
      {
        "name": "ONE",
        "properties": [
          {
             "name": "XXX"
          },
          {
             "name": "YY"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "TWO",
        "properties": []
      }
    ]
```

---

And I am trying to add the attribute to each object recursively using map in Reducer Function. Where I am getting following exception:

**TypeError: Cannot add property isChecked, object is not extensible**

```
projectData.myArr.map((item, index) => {   item.isChecked = false;   item.properties.map((value, index1) => {     value.isChecked = false;   }) });
```

I tried to use Object.assign() as it was discussed here: [Object is not extensible error when creating new attribute for array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798885/object-is-not-extensible-error-when-creating-new-attribute-for-array-of-objects)

```
let newData = data.map((item) => 
    Object.assign({}, item, {selected:false})
)
```

But this way allows me to add attributes for only top-level objects and not to inner objects.

How could I solve with nested objects related to the Redux Pattern?

Comment: what is 'projectData.myArr'? does myArr contains the array ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use nested [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) to create new objects at each level of desired mutation:

```js
projectData.myArr.map((item, itemIndex) => ({
  ...item,
  isChecked: false,
  properties: item.properties.map((value, valueIndex) => ({
    ...value,
    isChecked: false,
  }));
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

One can also try using the [Native StructuredClone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) or [lodash cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/#cloneDeep)(for node version before [V17.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70661021/structuredclone-not-available-in-typescript))

```
structuredClone(projectData).myArr.map((item, index) => {   item.isChecked = false;   item.properties.map((value, index1) => {     value.isChecked = false;   }) });
```

This will create a new clone thus none of the property in redux will be modified allowing one to freely work with the code.