# structuredClone() not available in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm running node.js v17.2.0 and TypeScript v4.5.4. I'm trying to use structuredClone() on a Map, and it doesn't seem to be working. ES2021 is targeted in tsconfig.json, and included in `lib`. Is this function just plain not available in TypeScript? Is there something else I need to include to get it?

@types/node is also installed, and I've made sure that it works in node.js environment.

[image: structuredClone working in node.js environment]

Comment: Seems like you have to call the function: let foo = structuredClone(value). This should help you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone

Comment: `structuredClone` is not part of ES2021. It's part of the web and node APIs. That's the lib you'll need to include (assuming it has been updated already, given that node 17 is still rather recent).

Comment: `your-package-manager install @types/node@^17`. If your `tsconfig.json` specifies `"types"` under `"compilerOptions"`, make sure `"node"` is listed as in `"types": ["node"]`.

Comment: @SARANSURYA the screenshot was just to prove it was available.

Comment: @AluanHaddad this should be the solution, thanks

Comment: @AluanHaddad I did that but still doesn't work. I installed the latest version (17.0.21). If I do a file search in my node_modules @types/node folder, there is no reference of "structuredClone"

Comment: @VincentV. I've just opened a PR in @types/node to add `structuredClone`: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/59434

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`structuredClone` is now present in `@types/node` [v17.0.29](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node/v/17.0.29):

Run the following command to have access to it:

`npm i --save-dev @types/node@17.0.29`

Answer (score 29):

`structuredClone` will be available in `lib.dom` of TypeScript v4.7 (as of 2022-05-19 it is currently in beta, but will be out soon). You can see where `structuredClone` was added to TypeScript [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/48577/files#diff-dc0eab937d15e62545da3ed7b4f40ad6b24f15dd88fbc6ceda2bfb4ed8356eb0R16794).

If you need to add it to your project temporarily until you can upgrade TypeScript, you can do that by putting the following definitions from the commit linked above into a `structuredClone.d.ts` file in your project (the base name doesn't matter, but the `.d.ts` does):

```typescript
interface WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope {
    structuredClone(value: any, options?: StructuredSerializeOptions): any;
}
declare function structuredClone( value: any, options?: StructuredSerializeOptions): any;
```

(`StructuredSerializeOptions` is already defined by `lib.dom.d.ts` for `postMessage`, so we don't need to add it.)

Then just remove that file when you've upgraded later.

Answer (score 1):

It was an ackowledged bug in Jest.

Jest supports structuredClone since v28.0.0-alpha.8 which is just above 28.0.0

https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/12628

jest-preset-angular is nearly at the stage of supporting that jest version.
According to the below issue 13.0.0-next-1 does.

https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/issues/1774

Comment: it seems still not to work with jest-preset-angular. do you know why?