# Faster ' find & reorder' logic in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am reordering the nodes in a certain level for a tree structure using the following recursive function. Reorder using the sort is not taking time, however recursively finding the parent node is taking time. how can I make this faster?

```
const reorderNodes = (tree, reorderedObject) => {
let copy = cloneDeep(tree);

// reorder
const reorder = (children) =>
  children?.slice().sort((a, b) => {
    return (
      reorderedObject.children.findIndex(reordered => reordered.id === a.id) -
      reorderedObject.children.findIndex(reordered => reordered.id === b.id)
    );
  });

if (!reorderedObject.parentId) {
  // if no parent
  copy = reorder(copy);
} else {
  // look recursively      
  copy = copy.map(el => {
    // found element to reorder.
    if (el.children) {
      if (el.id === reorderedObject.parentId) {
        el.children = reorder(el.children);
      } else {
        el.children = reorderNodes(el.children, reorderedObject);
      }
    }
    return el;
  });
}
return copy;
};
```

tree data

```
const tree = [
  {
    id: 'module-1',
    label: 'Unit',
    children: [{ id: 'field-zz', label: 'Name' }]
  },
  {
    id: 'module-2',
    label: 'Plans',
    children: [
      {
        id: 'level-1',
        label: 'Test-Level-1',
         children: [
          {
            id: 'level-1-1',
            label: 'Test-Level-1-1',
             children: [
              {
                id: 'field-1-1',
                label: 'ID',
              },
              {
                id: 'field-1-2',
                label: 'First upd',
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            id: 'level-1-2',
            label: 'Level-1-1-2',
            children: [
              {
                id: 'field-2-1',
                label: 'ID',
               
              },
              {
                id: 'field-2-2',
                label: 'First Upd',
                
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 'level-2',
        label: 'Test-Level-2',
       
        children: [
          {
            id: 'field-3',
            label: 'Keyword',
           
          },
          {
            id: 'field-4',
            label: 'Assignment',
            
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 'module-3',
        label: 'Find more',
        
        children: [
          {
            id: 'field-5',
            label: 'Description',
            
          },
          {
            id: 'field-6',
            label: 'ID',
            
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 'module-4',
    label: 'Data',
    
    children: [
      { id: 'field-33333', label: 'Date'},
      { id: 'field-44444', label: 'Time'}
    ]
  }
];
```

reorderedObject

```
const reorderedObject = {
        parentid: 'module-4',
        
        children: [
          { id: 'field-44444', label: 'Time'},
          { id: 'field-33333', label: 'Date'}
        ]
      }
```

If i have 4 level depth and 50 items in each level, it takes 10 sec to process.

Comment: please add your data.

Comment: okay, will add it now.

Comment: I don't see any reordered structure. But probably I have difficulties with understanding what the OP really wants. Could the OP try to be more precise with describing  the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be fast. I've implemented a recursive descent parser for a family tree app similar to what you're doing and have never exceeded a few tens of milliseconds drawing an entire family tree.

The main problem with your code is this:

```
let copy = cloneDeep(tree);
```

That's a whole lot of `malloc()` the javascript engine need to do in the background! Avoid copying memory in any language for speed.

If you need the original tree then clone just **once** before you enter the recursive function.

Comment: Similarly copying the array with `children?.slice()` will also slow you down a bit.

Comment: Not to mention the `map()` operation :)

Comment: if i am not using the clone deep I had another problem, the parameter tree is coming from a state and it goes back to the state. this state was not updating correctly.

Comment: Read the last sentence of my answer

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen. Self-updating operations like `x = x.map()` can be optimised by programming language runtimes using side-effect of copy-on-write. I'm not sure any javascript engine implements copy-on-write for values but Tcl will optimise it to not deallocate and reallocate memory (basically it reuses the objects that it knows will be garbage collected anyway). Tcl needs copy-on-write because that language does not have references/pointers - everything is a value (basically everything is immutable and changing anything means you create a new object and delete the old one)

Comment: you are right, my cloneDeep is what taking time. I was having some issues when updating redux store when I am not using cloneDeep.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to perform a graph search, and once you have found the node in question, sort its children.

Since the `sort()` operation sorts the array in place, there is no need for all the `slice()` and `map()` operations. You're recursively copying every level of the tree multiple times, and you have already cloned the entire tree to begin with.

I've implemented the graph search operation as a depth-first search:

```js
const reorderNodes = (tree, reorderedObject) => {
  const reorder = (nodes) => nodes.sort((a, b) => 
    reorderedObject.children.findIndex(reordered => reordered.id === a.id) -
    reorderedObject.children.findIndex(reordered => reordered.id === b.id)
  );

  const find = (nodes) => {
    if (!reorderedObject.parentId) return nodes;

    for (const node of nodes) {
      if (node.children) {
        if (node.id === reorderedObject.parentId) return node.children;
        
        const result = find(node.children);
        if (result) return result;
      }
    }
  }

  const copy = structuredClone(tree);
  const found = find(copy);

  reorder(found);

  return copy;
};

const tree = [{
  id: 'module-1',
  label: 'Unit',
  children: [{
    id: 'field-zz',
    label: 'Name'
  }]
}, {
  id: 'module-2',
  label: 'Plans',
  children: [{
    id: 'level-1',
    label: 'Test-Level-1',
    children: [{
      id: 'level-1-1',
      label: 'Test-Level-1-1',
      children: [{
          id: 'field-1-1',
          label: 'ID',
        },
        {
          id: 'field-1-2',
          label: 'First upd',
        }
      ]
    }, {
      id: 'level-1-2',
      label: 'Level-1-1-2',
      children: [{
        id: 'field-2-1',
        label: 'ID',

      }, {
        id: 'field-2-2',
        label: 'First Upd',

      }]
    }]
  }, {
    id: 'level-2',
    label: 'Test-Level-2',
    children: [{
      id: 'field-3',
      label: 'Keyword',

    }, {
      id: 'field-4',
      label: 'Assignment',

    }]
  }, {
    id: 'module-3',
    label: 'Find more',
    children: [{
      id: 'field-5',
      label: 'Description',

    }, {
      id: 'field-6',
      label: 'ID',

    }]
  }]
}, {
  id: 'module-4',
  label: 'Data',

  children: [{
    id: 'field-33333',
    label: 'Date'
  }, {
    id: 'field-44444',
    label: 'Time'
  }]
}];

const reorderedObject = {
  parentId: 'module-4',
  children: [{
    id: 'field-44444',
    label: 'Time'
  }, {
    id: 'field-33333',
    label: 'Date'
  }]
};

console.log(reorderNodes(tree, reorderedObject));
```

Comment: Yea, even in this code if i use the cloneDeep(), it slows down a lot. somehow the typescript in my project is not recognising structuredclone. Any other method I can use?

Comment: tried using structuredClone by https://stackoverflow.com/a/72306923/1521686
however this is also slow.