# structuredClone not available on global object in nodejs app

Tags: node.js, typescript, global, structured-clone

`structuredClone` doesn't work in my NodeJS app. When I try to use it I get the error: `structuredClone is not defined nodejs`.

If I create a simple file, and run:

```js
console.log({
    globals: Object.keys(global),
    structuredClone: global.structuredClone
});
```

I get:

```
{
  globals: [
    'global',
    'clearInterval',
    'clearTimeout',
    'setInterval',
    'setTimeout',
    'queueMicrotask',
    'performance',
    'clearImmediate',
    'setImmediate'
  ],
  structuredClone: undefined
}
```

I've updated my node modules as per [this question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70661021/structuredclone-not-available-in-typescript). My `package.json` includes:

```json
 "dependencies": {
    "ajv-draft-04": "^1.0.0",
    "ajv-formats": "^2.1.1",
    "aws-appsync": "^4.1.7",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1205.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^29.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.7.15",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.36.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.36.1",
    "eslint": "^8.23.0",
    "jest": "^28.0.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19",
    "serverless-plugin-typescript": "^2.1.2",
    "ts-jest": "^28.0.8",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.8.2"
  }
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": ".build",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["es2015"],
    "rootDir": "./"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why it should be available on the `global` object. The way I understand it is that you can use the function straight away:

```
const obj = structuredClone(anotherObject)
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone

Also, keep in mind that you need to run Node.js 17+.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and (like [robbash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/840238/robbash) said) it was because I was running an old version of node.js. structuredClone() is only available from version 17. I upgraded and it works now.