# How to assign objects to an array

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am querying data from firebase, I then want to assign the fetch data to be an array

This is my code

```
         let list = [];
        dispatch(fetchUsersPending());
        db.collection("users").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                list.push({...doc.data()});
                console.log('All Users: ', list);
                dispatch(fetchUsersSuccess(list));
            });
        }).catch((error) => {
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            console.log('Error fetching data', errorMessage);
            dispatch(fetchUsersFailed({ errorMessage }));
          });;
```

But in my console am getting an error showing `Error fetching data Cannot add property 1, object is not extensible in react firebase`

Comment: try removing curly braces from ...doc.data(). It is already supposed to be an object

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798885/object-is-not-extensible-error-when-creating-new-attribute-for-array-of-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your current approach also causes to many unnecessary dispatches to the store. With the following solution you only map your array to documents once and then dispatch them all at once.

With async/await

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
        dispatch(fetchUsersPending());
        const users = (await db.collection('users').get()).docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data()}));
        dispatch(fetchUsersSuccess(users));
    } catch (errorMessage) {
        dispatch(fetchUsersFailed({ errorMessage }));
    }
}
```

With .then()

```
const fetchData = () => {
        dispatch(fetchUsersPending());
        const users = db.collection('users').get().then((snapshot) => {
            const users = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data() }));
            dispatch(fetchUsersSuccess(users));
    }).catch((errorMessage) {
        dispatch(fetchUsersFailed({ errorMessage }));
    });
}
```