# How to update a variable in class of Object In Typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, class, object

I have a class of object

Class file (consumption.ts)

```
export class ConsumptionDetails {
Id: string;
Status: string;
Description: string;
Quantity: number;
}
```

Function 1: (consumption.component.ts)

```
this.lineItems$.subscribe((result: BindingState<ConsumptionDetails>) => {
 if(result){
   this.tempObj = result;
 }
}
```

Function 2: (consumption.component.ts)

```
this.tempObj.Status = 'Submitted';
console.log(this.tempObj);
```

Here 'Submitted' status not updated with 'tempObj.Status', Instead of I am getting error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot add property Status, object is not extensible
```

Comment: Is it an option to change `ConsumptionDetails`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798885/object-is-not-extensible-error-when-creating-new-attribute-for-array-of-objects