# Dynamically adding a number of properties to a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, object

The scenario is to dynamically add some properties to JavaScript object at once.

For example, there is an object "data"

```
var data = {
    PropertyA: 1,
    PropertyB: 2,
    PropertyC: 3,
}
```

Then add extra data to "data"

```
if(true){
    var extraData = {
        PropertyD: 4,
        PropertyE: 5,
        PropertyF: 6,
    }
} else {
    var extraData = {
        PropertyX: 4,
        PropertyY: 5,
        PropertyZ: 6,
    }
}
```

What is the best way or the easiest to add "extraData" to "Data"?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Comment: `Object.assign(data, condition? extraDataDEF: extraDataXYZ);`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The most modern approach would be to use ES6's [**spread**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
const moreData = { ...data, extraData };
```

Alternatively this would be the traditional way of doing it:

```
var moreData = Object.assign({}, data, extraData);
```

Comment: Yes, this is ES6.

Comment: What library do I need to include for this?

Comment: Adding to this answer, you can read about the difference between assign and spread here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32925460/object-spread-vs-object-assign

Comment: You would use something like Babel: https://babeljs.io/docs/setup#installation. If that isn't an option I've provided an alternative solution in my updated answer.

Comment: @PatoSalazar Aside from the risk of mutation there really is no difference.

Comment: Object spread is not on ES6. Is currently in stage 3 https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Should I even ask why there's downvotes on this answer...? smh

Comment: @CarlEdwards 1) It's not ES6, as suggested; 2) OP asked to add to `Data`, not create a new object with new properties. IRL these 2 are different things. 3) There's not explanation at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.assign(data, extraData);
```

If you don't want to mutate the value of data, you can do something like this instead:

```
var newData = Object.assign({}, data, extraData);
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a good way to do that:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function(){
       var data = {
            PropertyA: 1,
            PropertyB: 2,
            PropertyC: 3,
        };
        if(true){
            var extraData = {
                PropertyD: 4,
                PropertyE: 5,
                PropertyF: 6,
            };
        } else {
            var extraData = {
                PropertyX: 4,
                PropertyY: 5,
                PropertyZ: 6,
            };
        }

        var object = $.extend({}, data, extraData);

        console.log(object);

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why bring in an entire library like jQuery when something like this can be easily done in Javascript?

Comment: Good question! Why does jQuery even exist, javascript is there.