# failed to concat nested array of object in setState of react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

What's wrong with below code?

```
this.setState({
  album: {
    ...this.state.album,
    photos: [
      ...this.state.album.photos,
      { url : newUrl }
    ]
  }
})
```

It worked if photos have something, but if album is an empty object, I will got this error

```
Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings album is an empty object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use: `(...this.state.album.photos || [])` so it parses the empty array at first:

```js
const state = {
  album: {
    photos: undefined
  }
}

const newState = {
  album: {
    ...state.album,
    photos: [
      ...(state.album.photos || []),
      { url: 'newUrl' }
    ]
  }
}

console.log(newState)
```

Comment: what about using `Object.assign()` as I have done in the answer below? Which one would be better?

Comment: IMO, there's no `better` solution nor right or wrong :). 
About differences between `Object.assign` and spread operator you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32925460/object-spread-vs-object-assign) answer :)

Comment: I also answered your question based on your code sample. You were already using spread operator in it.

Comment: I am aware of the difference, I am saying short-circuiting vs. chaining?

Comment: I'd go for short-circuiting :)

Comment: this is elegant, many thanks! I have to be aware of default empty arr next time doing spread!

Comment: @XieXieFang you can either control this way or initiate `state.album.photos` as an empty array. Both of which will work eventually :)

Comment: I think better to init an empty array, it's more readable and less logic.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's the expected behaviour. The spread operator (`...`) will spread, that is, expand everything provided. If that's `null`, it can't possibly do that, right?

You can try something like:

```
...( Object.assign( {}, this.state.album.photos )
```

Comment: The `...` is the spread operator. `Object.assign()` will give us a new object based on the `photos` property. If it's null, it'll be an empty object and, hence, the spread operator will do nothing. However, if it does have content, it'll just spread it normally.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Short circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) concept and put `||[]` with `state.albums.photos`, if albums will be blank object then `(photos=undefined || [])` will return an empty array.

Use this:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    album: {
        ...prevState.album,
        photos: [
            (...prevState.album.photos || []),
            { url : newUrl }
        ]
    }
}))
```

Use `updater function` and `prevState` to compute the next state value.