# DRY React method of rendering same props & text to different component types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, design-patterns

In React, is there a recommended or industry-standard technique for conditionally rendering different component types that have the same props and innerHTML?

To be specific I'm swapping between `<Text />` and `<TextInput />` in React Native.

I would check state, if blah is true then render `<ComponentA />`, else `<ComponentB />`. However they'll take identical props/innerText.

As an example:

Not DRY

```
var component = <CoolComponent quantity="42" color="green" write="true">some stuff</CoolComponent>;
if (true) {
  component = <ADifferentOne quantity="42" color="green" write="true">some stuff</ADifferentComponent>;
} else if (false) {
  <ANewComponent quantity="42" color="green" write="true">some stuff</ANewComponent>
}
```

The best solution I've found is:

```
var TagType = CoolComponent;
if (true) {
  TagType = ADifferentOne;
} else if (false) {
  TagType = ANewComponent
}
<TagType quantity="42" color="green" write="true">Some stuff</TagType>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const ComponentSwitcher = ({ props }) => {
  return props.if ? <props.onTrue {...props} /> : <props.onFalse {...props} />
}
```

Usage:

```
<ComponentSwitcher if={myVar} onTrue={ADifferentOne} onFalse={ANewComponent
} quantity="42" color="green" write="true">some stuff</ComponentSwitcher>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could extract it to the dedicated component if you'd prefer to. Just use [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/how-do-you-use-the-conditional-operator-in-javascript) & [spread object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32926019/2926641) for this case

```
const NewComponent = ({ props }) => (
  your_condition ?
    <ADifferentOne {...props} /> :
    <ANewComponent {...props} />
)
```