# How to use map() loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a structure like this:

```
let MainItem = [
 {
    "Id": "1",
    "Cost": "1000"
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "Cost": "5000"
  },
  {
    "Id": "3",
    "Cost": "2000"
  },
  {
    "Id": "4",
    "Cost": "3000"
  }
];
```

I am going to change the value of `Cost` each of the elements with `map()` loop and store it in `NewMainItem`.

```
let NewMainItem = MainItem.map((item, i) => {
  item.cost = item.cost + 1000
  return item
});

console.log(MainItem)
console.log(NewMainItem)
```

The main problem is that by changing `Cost` in `NewMainItem`, the value of
 `Cost` in `MainItem` will be changed too, but I don not want to do this. By using `map()` loop why the main object (`MainItem` ) will be changed too?

Comment: Deep clone the `item` within the `map` callback.

Comment: @adiga I'd say [Why does map mutate array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50990321/691711) is an even better target since that question and this do not seem to understand that the item in the iteration callback ***is*** the actual item.

Comment: here `item.cost = ...` you change the property of an existing object. Wether you do that inside a loop, or wherever, **you change** the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to create new objects from the existing ones, not modify them.

You could use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to create a new item like this:

`{ ...item, Cost: parseFloat(item.Cost) + 100 };`

Here [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) was used because the `Cost`s values are set as string in your snippet. Feel free to change this as it fits your needs.

See below snippet:

```js
let MainItem = [
 {
    "Id": "1",
    "Cost": "1000"
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "Cost": "5000"
  },
  {
    "Id": "3",
    "Cost": "2000"
  },
  {
    "Id": "4",
    "Cost": "3000"
  }
];

let NewMainItem = MainItem.map((item, i) => {
  return { ...item, Cost: parseFloat(item.Cost) + 100 };
});
console.log(MainItem)
console.log(NewMainItem)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could assign a new object with the wanted changed value.

```js
var mainItem = [{ Id: "1", Cost: "1000" }, { Id: "2", Cost: "5000" }, { Id: "3", Cost: "2000" }, { Id: "4", Cost: "3000" }],
    newMainItem = mainItem.map(item => Object.assign({}, item, { Cost: +item.Cost + 1000 }));

console.log(mainItem);
console.log(newMainItem);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```