# What purpose does spread syntax inside an object literal ({...object}) serve?

Tags: javascript, spread-syntax

I have read the answer on [I don't understand about spread syntax inside objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64603492/cant-understand-about-spread-operator-in-object) but still don't quite understand the purpose of using (specifically) `{...object}`.

**What purpose does `{...object}` serve?**

I have tested this in the node REPL, say I made an object:

```
> const object = { foo: "hello", bar: "world" };
```

And use the spread operator inside a new object literal to refer to it:

```
> { ...object }
{ foo: 'hello', bar: 'world' }
```

The output is the same as just using the object itself:

```
> object
{ foo: 'hello', bar: 'world' }
```

What purpose does `{...object}` serve?

Comment: No, that is not the same object. It is a (shallow) copy of the object.

Comment: `const object = { foo: "hello", bar: "world" }; const foo = { ...object }; object.foo = "bar"; console.log(object, foo);`

Comment: @trincot I didn't state it was the same object but rather that output is the same as just using the object itself.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, I've updated title to say 'syntax' not 'operator'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the same object. It makes a shallow copy of the object's own, enumerable properties (like `Object.assign({}, object)` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)). You use it when you want...a copy, with the object's own, enumerable properties. :-D

For example, with any of several MVC or similar libraries, you might use it when updating state, since state shouldn't be modified directly:

```
this.setState(oldState => ({...oldState, prop: "new value"}));
```

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder. I already check the question was a duplicate and there's no other answers.

Comment: @mikemaccana - I wouldn't be surprised if there are some out there. It's really hard to search for this. I haven't found a good one yet.

Comment: lol it's been marked as a duplicate of general purpose questions about what the spread syntax means. Which isn't the question.

Comment: @mikemaccana The first is the _"catch all"_ for questions about operators/symbols that lacks an explanation for this shallow-copy use-case. The second one is wrong imho. The third one is not perfect but has good hints. The forth explains the details on your use-case. Not optimal but the last one should be enough for an answer on your question.

Comment: @Andreas I'm not sure on the SO policy on when questions are different but answers from other questions help. But yes I agree - the first 3 links are irrelevant, the fourth has actual useful answers.

Comment: @Andreas - Good analysis if you don't mind my saying so. I've moved the useful one to the top and removed the one that wasn't a good target for this.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder if you wanted to make it narrower, just the 'Object copy using Spread operator actually shallow or deep?' would be the more relevant.