# Spread Operator ... used with function call in props of Tab in material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-props

I have seen this `<Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(1)} />` in Material UI where function is called with in the props with ... spread operator When i try speratly as

```
console.log(...a11yProps(3));
```

i get error ,anyone can tell what is happening here `<Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(1)} />` how does spread operator used with function call ?

Comment: [See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64612639). The beginning talks extensively about why "spread" is not an operator and why that matters. In short `...fn()` will do *different things* based on the context. Object spread `{...fn()}` ***must*** receive an object, while spreading into arguments `console.log(...fn())` ***must*** receive an iterable. Most of the times, these don't overlap.

Comment: @VLAZ I have read your answer but i didn't get the answer for spread syntax used with function call ?
my asking this after along time because i'm facing this again !

Comment: Let me reiterate - spreading is not a single thing. Depends on the context. Within a function call, you can only spread *arrays* (or other iterables). Spreading *an object* is a completely different thing and does not work within a function call. Objects can be spread into other objects. So `...x` will vary in what happens both based on what `x` is and also what the context is `fn( ...x )` and `{ ...x }` are different operations because the context is different.

Comment: @VLAZ hmm sir any better demo ! please , sorry for interrupting .

Comment: https://jsbin.com/cesicap/edit?js,console

Comment: @VLAZ so here`...fn()` first function is called which returns an object then thats is spread ,am i right !

Comment: `allyProps()` must be returning an object, hence why spreading that object into a function call throws an error.

Comment: I guess `console.log({...allyProps()}) ` this would be correct !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo

```
function fn(x, y, z) {
  console.log("fn() called with", x, y, z);
}
let x;

x = ["a", "b", "c"];


fn( ...x ); //function call with spread of an array

console.log("spreading into an object", { ...x } ); // spreading into an object clones the properties of the array

x = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};

console.log("spreading into an object", { ...x } ); // spreading object into an object clones it

fn( ...x ); //spreading an object into a function call is an error



function fb2(){
  return obj = {object : 'new Object'}
}

console.log({...fb2()}.object);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just do:

```
console.log(a11yProps(3));
```

Comment: I know that what i'm asking is that spread operator used with fuction and passed as props ```<Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(1)} />```

Comment: @MuhammadMehdi yes it is passed as a prop there, if you want to console.log it you have to log it without spread operator, what do you want to achieve here? did you even test my answer?

Comment: I want to know that how did  it call function with starting spread operator !