# The function makes the correct conclusion when console.log stands above the function call

Tags: javascript, node.js

The function makes the correct conclusion when console.log is placed above the function call. I'm not kidding, I checked several times by removing and adding the console.log.
Version node.js v16.4.2.
The input is correct. I also tried to reproduce the problem in a different environment, where I got the correct output without console.log.

```
async function styleQg(seance, date, durationSeance, questId, standardPrice) {
    const dateNow = (new Date()).toISOString().split('T')[0]
    seance = seance
        .filter(e => durationSeance === "3600" ?
            e.time.split(':')[1] === "00" :
            e.time.split(":")[1].split("")[1] !== "5")
        .map(e => ({date: date, ...e, price: standardPrice}))
    if (date === dateNow) {
        console.log(await expiredSeance(seance))
        seance = await expiredSeance(seance)
    }

    return seance
}

async function expiredSeance(seance) {

    seance = seance.map(e => {
        if (e.time < new Date().toLocaleString("ru-RU", {timeZone: "Europe/Moscow"}).split(' ')[1]) {
            return {...e, ...e.is_free = false}
        } else {
            return {...e}
        }
    })
    return seance
}
```

Input data(styleQg):

```
[
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '10:00', is_free: true, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '11:00', is_free: true, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '12:00', is_free: false, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '13:00', is_free: true, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '14:00', is_free: true, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '15:00', is_free: true, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '16:00', is_free: true, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '17:00', is_free: true, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '18:00', is_free: true, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '19:00', is_free: true, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '20:00', is_free: true, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '21:00', is_free: true, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '22:00', is_free: true, price: 5000 }
]
```

Output data(with console.log):

```
[
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '10:00', is_free: false, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '11:00', is_free: false, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '12:00', is_free: false, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '13:00', is_free: false, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '14:00', is_free: false, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '15:00', is_free: false, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '16:00', is_free: true, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '17:00', is_free: true, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '18:00', is_free: true, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '19:00', is_free: true, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '20:00', is_free: true, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '21:00', is_free: true, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '22:00', is_free: true, price: 5000 }
]
```

Output data(without console.log):

```
[
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '10:00', is_free: true, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '11:00', is_free: true, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '12:00', is_free: false, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '13:00', is_free: true, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '14:00', is_free: true, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '15:00', is_free: true, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '16:00', is_free: true, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '17:00', is_free: true, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '18:00', is_free: true, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '19:00', is_free: true, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '20:00', is_free: true, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '21:00', is_free: true, price: 5000 },
  { date: '2021-07-31', time: '22:00', is_free: true, price: 5000 }
]
```

Comment: What is `seance`?

Comment: input data in the form of an array of objects, an example is in my post

Comment: Then why are you using `await` here? If these are just arrays and plain objects there's no need for `async`.

Comment: I may not use this, but it doesn't change anything anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing mutation *while* spreading: `{...e, ...e.is_free = false}` This will not transfer the new value you assign to the new object you create. Instead it just changes *the old object*. Using `...e.is_free = false` will try to spread the assignment value `false` into the object [which does not do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64603492/i-dont-understand-about-spread-syntax-inside-objects).

It is not the `console.log` that changes anything, it is calling the function twice. The second call will use the updated values:

```js
const x = { is_free: true };

//changes `x.is_free` to `false` but `y` already used the old value
const y = { ...x, ...x.is_free = false}; 

//changes `x.is_free` is already `false` so `z` gets that value
const z = { ...x, ...x.is_free = false};

console.log(x);
console.log(y);
console.log(z);
```

The *correct* way to copy an object and change a value is `{...e, is_free: false}` that will not rely on any mutations and side-effects:

```js
const x = { is_free: true };
const y = { ...x, is_free: false}; 
const z = { ...x, is_free: false};

console.log(x);
console.log(y);
console.log(z);
```

Comment: I don't understand how I could allow this to happen