# What's the best way to initialize an object with defaults where values are omitted in Ecmascript 6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's say I want to declare an object `bar` and set it's values to be those of the object `foo`, but I'm uncertain whether `foo` will have all the requisite properties.  I also want to preserve falsy values like `""` from `foo`, rather than reverting to defaults.  For example:

```
var foo = somefunc();
console.log(foo);
//{prop1: "", prop2: "works"}

var defaults = {prop1: "default1", prop2: "default2", prop3: "default3"}
/* some piece of code */
console.log(bar);
//should log: {prop1: "", prop2: "works", prop3: "default3"}
```

What would be the best `/* some piece of code */` to use in Ecmascript 6 to initialize with defaults like this?

Comment: Rather than using destructuring defaults, you could spread the defaults and then the vaules, or use `Object.assign`?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "spread the defaults".

Comment: Create a new object from `defaults` and `bar` using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax it is very similar to `Object.assign`

Comment: Also, you can use spread operator to achieve the same result. `const result = {...defaults, ...foo }`;

Comment: I see, thanks. Perhaps it should be an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can elegantly use the spread operator to achieve this,

```
var foo = {prop1: "", prop2: "works"};
console.log(foo);

var defaults = {prop1: "default1", prop2: "default2", prop3: "default3"}
var bar = {...defaults, ...foo}
console.log(bar);
```

Comment: Are there reasons to favour this over `Object.assign` beyond the fact it's prettier?

Comment: Good explanation provided here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32925460/object-spread-vs-object-assign

Comment: Might just be a case of not using the right terminology but note that object spread is not part of ES6.

Comment: Partly not using the right terminology, in that I probably should have asked about "modern Javascript" rather than specifically Ecmascript6, but since it's standardized, this works nicely for my purposes at least.

Answer (score 3):

Is that works for you?

```js
var foo = {prop1: "", prop2: "works"};
var defaults = {prop1: "default1", prop2: "default2", prop3: "default3"}
var bar = Object.assign({},defaults,foo)
console.log(bar); //{prop1: "", prop2: "works", prop3: "default3"}
```

Comment: Thanks! you can read more about Object.assign() [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using `Object.assign` with an empty object as the target, and `defaults` and `foo` as the sources, in that order.

```
let bar = Object.assign({}, defaults, foo);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var new_object={ ...defaults, ...foo }
```

Comment: Is there a reason to favour this approach over the `Object.assign` solutions already mentioned, beyond aesthetic preference?