# Why do we need to spread the state before updating it in a Redux reducer?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux

Just a simple question for the pros.  I am building a reducer and a piece of the code looks like this:

```
export const cusDataReducer = (state = cusDataInitialState, action) => {    
    let newState = {...state}
    switch (action.type) {
        case "CUS_READ":
            newState.data = action.value;
            newState.loading = false;                        
            break;
...
```

The question I have is what is the difference between `state` and `{...state}` in this case?  If I change `newState=state` the code breaks.  Console logs of `state` and `{...state}`, however, look exactly the same.

This is my store:

```
import {cusDataReducer} from './cusdata'

let rootReducer = combineReducers({
    cusdata: cusDataReducer
});
export const Store = createStore(rootReducer,applyMiddleware(thunk))
```

Comment: [Why can't I directly modify a component's state, really?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37755997/1218980)

Comment: Just FYI: [Object spread vs. `Object.assign`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32925460/1218980)

Comment: While the following is for a React state, the same (immutability) principle applies to Redux reducers: [How to update nested state properties in React](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43040721/1218980)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't create a new object:

```
let newState = state;
```

The variable `newState` simply points to the same object as `state`.  Modifying that object is mutating the current state, which is bad.

This, however, does create a new object:

```
let newState = {...state};
```

The spread operator (`...`) is basically a very convenient shorthand for populating that new object with each property of the existing object.  A longer version might be something like:

```
let newState = {
    prop1: state.prop1,
    prop2: state.prop2,
    //etc.
};
```

By creating a new object, it's no longer the current actual state.  You can mutate your new object all you like.  Upon returning it, Redux will replace the entire current state with the entire new state.

Comment: Makes quite a bit of sense.  Thanks!

Comment: So how is it known which reducer key to update in the store if I add say another reducer called "emldata"?

Comment: @Elcid_91: I'm not sure what you mean.  The main structure of the reducer is that `switch` which determines which action type is being invoked.  Those should all be mutually exclusive.  Once you get into the correct `case` then the code is specifically written to perform the necessary updates to state.  Whatever fields you need to update for that action, you'd update them.

Comment: OK, I will give it another go, I ask because I had two reducers in the store that were structurally identical.  Loaded one key on the store but the other key loaded with the same data....very odd.  I will clean muy code up and post in another question if it happens again..Thanks!