# How to merge Array Key value from another Key in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

```
[
    0: {employeeId: "2", name: "chandan", email: "chandan@gmail.com"}
    1: {gender: "male"}
]
```

I want this Array like this:

```
[
  0: {employeeId: "2", name: "chandan", email: "chandan@gmail.com", gender: "male"}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the spread operator to create a new object, that will copy over the properties of the two existing objects.

```
arr[0]={...arr[0],...arr[1]};
```

Comment: Array length is not static So I can't use static [0] the keys is dynamic it would be helpful if you suggest code with dynamic value;

Comment: So your array has multiple values ? Not only one?

Comment: Józef Podlecki's answer allows for a non-static array length.

Answer (score 2):

`array.reduce` and spread can help you

```js
const arr = [{
    employeeId: "2",
    name: "chandan",
    email: "chandan@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    gender: "male"
  }
]

const result = arr.reduce((acc, obj) => ({
  ...acc,
  ...obj
}), {});

console.log(result);
```

--Edit

`Object.assign` flavor ( seems to be 1% slower on chrome 83 though)

```js
const arr = [{
    employeeId: "2",
    name: "chandan",
    email: "chandan@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    gender: "male"
  }
]

const result = arr.reduce((acc, obj) => Object.assign(acc, obj), {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This will do it dynamically, regardless of how many elements are in the array. It loops through the array, spreading the results over and over again.

Comment: Now I wonder if `Object.assign` is good alternative to that. Would have to make some tests on jsperf

Comment: Added variant with object.assign

Comment: @JózefPodlecki any difference between spread & Object.assign?

Comment: [Apart from availability between browsers and slight performance there is none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32925460/object-spread-vs-object-assign)

Answer (score 1):

use `reduce` without initial value will agreggate.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    employeeId: "2",
    name: "chandan",
    email: "chandan@gmail.com",
  },
  {
    gender: "male",
  },
];

const output = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => Object.assign(acc, curr));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this by mapping it and then taking `fromEntries`:

```js
var data=[ {employeeId: "2", name: "chandan", email: "chandan@gmail.com"}, {gender: "male"}];

var result = Object.fromEntries(data.flatMap(k=>Object.entries(k)));

console.log(result);
```