# Array in React being mutated

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dplyr

I've read several entries on keeping arrays from being mutated in React, but I can't figure out why my original array is being mutated. In the componentDidMount, I'm going to the database and retrieving win-loss records for each week and saving the records to state. (Each week a team plays three games.)

```
async componentDidMount() {
    document.body.style.background = '#9bcaf1';
    await this.getInitialStats();
    this.processStats();
  }

  async getInitialStats(): Promise<void> {
    const allRecords: TeamWeek[] = await getAllResults();
    this.setState({
      allRecords,
    });
  }
```

Then I call a second function that takes each team's record for the week and combines them into one record. So if a team has lost all three games in each of three weeks, that should combine to one record that shows the team lost nine games. I save that as a separate state variable. However the original state array is being mutated as well, even though I thought I was cloning the array. I can do a push into the cloned array, and it works correctly, but something with the function is screwing things up.

```
processStats(): void {
    const allRecordsClone = [...this.state.allRecords];
    const combinedRecords: TeamWeek[] = calculateOverallStats(allRecordsClone);
    this.setState({
      combinedRecords,
    });
  }
export const calculateOverallStats = (allRecords: TeamWeek[]): TeamWeek[] => {
  const allRecordsClone = [...allRecords];
  const combinedRecs: TeamWeek[] = [];
  const teamNamesCollected: string[] = [];

  // Combine wins, losses, ties, points
  allRecordsClone.forEach((rec) => {
    const { team_name, wins, losses, ties, total_points } = rec;
    if (!teamNamesCollected.includes(team_name)) {
      combinedRecs.push(rec);
      teamNamesCollected.push(team_name);
    } else {
      const teamIndex = combinedRecs.findIndex((combRec) => combRec.team_name === team_name);
      combinedRecs[teamIndex].wins += wins;
      combinedRecs[teamIndex].losses += losses;
      combinedRecs[teamIndex].ties += ties;
      combinedRecs[teamIndex].total_points += total_points;
    }
  });
  return allRecordsClone;
};
```

Any thoughts? I cannot figure this out.

Comment: Copying an array via spread still creates references to any objects included in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying an array via spread still creates references to any objects included in the array.

```js
const array1 = [1, {a: 2}, [3,4]];
const array2 = [...array1];

array2[0] = "unchanged in array1";
array2[1].a = "changed in both";
array2[2][0] = "arrays are Objects";

console.log('array1: ', array1);
// array1:  [1, {"a": "changed in both"}, ["arrays are Objects", 4]]
console.log('array2: ', array2);
// array2:  ["unchanged in array1", {"a": "changed in both"}, ["arrays are Objects", 4]]
```

Given that, you'll need to use `Object.assign()` or spread each object or array before pushing into the combinedArray.

The React docs cover this issue here: [Immutability Helpers](https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html)

Answer (score 1):

@pilchard's answer is correct. First you need to create copy of each property or element of array, and then push it to parent combined array. You need can use either of `Object.assign()` or spread operator to do this.

[Object spread vs. Object.assign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32925460/object-spread-vs-object-assign)

Comment: `Object.assign()` still creates references to nested objects.