# React Controlled Component Doesn't Rerender/Update Like I Expect

Tags: reactjs

So, I was refactoring a React component after reading more about React principles of *[lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)* and in particular after reading [*this about derived state*](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-controlled-component).

I had a component like so (before the refactor) that was working but now I realize was duplicating state among multiple sources of truth (in the parent and the child):

```
const ChildComponent = ({
  prevStep,
  nextStep,
  parentStateData,
  updateParentStateData,
}) => {
  const [childState, updateChildState] = useState(
    parentStateData["thisChildData"]
  );

  const updateParentStateDataFromChild = () => {
    return updateParentStateData(
      Object.assign(parentStateData, { thisChildData: childState })
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => updateParentStateDataFromChild(), [childState]);

  return (
    <div className="text-center">
      <h1 className="step-title">Choose Child State</h1>
      <div class="state-size-buttons">
        <Button
          onClick={() => updateChildState(1)}
          active={childState === 1}
          className="mt-3"
          variant="light"
          size="lg"
        >
          1
        </Button>
        <Button
          onClick={() => updateChildState(2)}
          active={childState === 2}
          className="mt-3"
          variant="light"
          size="lg"
        >
          2
        </Button>
        <Button
          onClick={() => updateChildState(3)}
          active={childState === 3}
          className="mt-3"
          variant="light"
          size="lg"
        >
          3
        </Button>
      </div>
      <Button onClick={() => prevStep()} className="mr-2" variant="light">
        Go Back
      </Button>
      <Button disabled={!childState} onClick={() => nextStep()} variant="light">
        Next
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Again, this worked but it's not good (I think) because it duplicates state. The `ChildComponent` receives the parent state (`parentStateData`) and an update function for that state (`updateParentStateData`) but duplicates that state in its own `childState` and `updateChildState` - which in turn updates the parent using a `useEffect()` hook -> when child state updates, update the parent state.

So, I started my refactor, like this:

```
const ChildComponent = ({
  prevStep,
  nextStep,
  parentStateData,
  updateParentStateData,
}) => {
  const updateState = (data) => {
    return updateParentStateData(
      Object.assign(parentStateData, { thisChildData: data })
    );
  };

  const nextDisabled = !parentStateData["thisChildData"];

  return (
    <div className="text-center">
      <h1 className="step-title">Choose A State</h1>
      <div class="state-size-buttons">
        <Button
          onClick={() => updateState(1)}
          active={parentStateData["thisChildData"] === 1}
          className="mt-3"
          variant="light"
          size="lg"
        >
          1
        </Button>
        <Button
          onClick={() => updateState(2)}
          active={parentStateData["thisChildData"] === 2}
          className="mt-3"
          variant="light"
          size="lg"
        >
          2
        </Button>
        <Button
          onClick={() => updateState(3)}
          active={parentStateData["thisChildData"] === 3}
          className="mt-3"
          variant="light"
          size="lg"
        >
          3
        </Button>
      </div>
      <Button onClick={() => prevStep()} className="mr-2" variant="light">
        Go Back
      </Button>
      <Button
        disabled={nextDisabled}
        onClick={() => nextStep()}
        variant="light"
      >
        Next
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This time as you can see, there is no internal state and the parent state object simply gets updated at the relevant key using `Object.assign()`.

But my problem is *these state changes never get reflected in my view*. If I do a React component inspector I see the state is changing (although it seems to lag) but the view doesn't change. Most critically, the `nextDisabled` constant and variants of that (I tried putting that logic directly into the Next button `<Button disabled={nextDisabled} onClick={()=>nextStep()} variant="light">Next</Button>`) don't ever change. So the parent state gets updated, but `!parentStateData['thisChildData']` never changes value or never runs again... so what gets *rerendered* when the props (via the change in `parentStateData`) change? Why doesn't the simple validation on the next button work as I expect when I update the parent state? That is, once I select a number using the buttons (no longer `0` from the default) I would expect it to not be disabled (example: `!1` is false - so not disabled as its for the `disabled` prop).

**But it never changes!**

It stays evaluated to `true` despite the state updating in the parent and therefore the props changing in the child. So somewhere I have a conceptual error. Any help here would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I think this is because you are returning the same object. Be careful of immutability. Try: return updateParentStateData(
      {...parentStateData, thisChildData: data }
    );

Comment: @StéphaneVeyret I dont' think so, that's what `Object.assign()` does, no? Returns a new object?

Comment: @Summer_Developer, no, `Object.assign()` returns the first given parameter, after assigning the given properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React, and most of the tools working with it, are based on the fact that states are immutable. It means that if you want to update a state, you must not change values in the same object, but you need to provide a new object.

So, the following is an error, because it updates the value of the state:

```js
  const updateState = (data) => {
    return updateParentStateData(
      Object.assign(parentStateData, { thisChildData: data })
    );
  };
```

Instead, you should create a new object, for example:

```js
  const updateState = (data) => {
    return updateParentStateData(
      Object.assign({}, parentStateData, { thisChildData: data })
    );
  };
```

I think that your first example is working only because it really updates the child property.

Comment: I think this is wrong. This is what `Object.assign()` does. See this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32925460/object-spread-vs-object-assign

Comment: Oh... or would I do it like this `Object.assign({},parentStateData,{ thisChildData: data })`?

Comment: Look carefully to this question: the first given parameter of `Object.assign()` is a new empty object. This is not what you are doing.

Comment: Yes, you can do this. I will update my answer to use `assign`.