# how to constant object or remain object values same in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, constants, findbugs

Here is basic example where I want to explain my requirement . I want not to change object a values after assigning it to const b and changing its values .I want console result original object a values not after assign values . how can I achive this in console name :abc, number 123

```js
const a ={
name:"abc",
number:123
}
const b = a
b.name ="xyz";
b.number = 321
 console.log(a);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Instead of `const b = a`, `const b = globalThis.structuredClone(a)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply do this with b so that b will not reference to a

`const b = {...a}`

Answer (score 2):

Use [Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) to **prevent modifying an object**.
Just, before doing so you might want to (optionally) spread  your original object `{...a}` values into `b` beforehand, (or by using [Object.assign()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32925460/object-spread-vs-object-assign)) in order to keep the `a` object values still modifiable:

```js
const a = {
  name: "abc",
  number: 123
};

const b = {...a};
Object.freeze(b);

a.name = "Still modifiable";
a.number = 999;
console.log(a); // {"name": "Still modifiable!", "number": 999}

b.name = "xyz";
b.number = 321;
console.log(b); // {"name": "abc", "number": 123}
```