# Merge arrays of objects manteining all the properties

Tags: javascript

I have 2 array of objects and I want to merge them.

```
var fruits = [
    {name: 'pear', cultivar: '', color: 'yellowgreen', size: '6'},
    {name: 'apple', cultivar: 'Annurca', color: 'red', size: '5'},
    {name: 'apple', cultivar: 'fuji', color: 'red', size: '4'}
]; 

var quantity = [
    {name: 'pear', number: '15'},
    {name: 'apple', number: '50', scad: '2018'},
    {name: 'apple', number: '50'}
];
```

What I want is:

```
var all = [
    {name: 'pear', cultivar: '', color: 'yellowgreen', size: '6', number: '15', scad: 'NaN'},
    {name: 'apple', cultivar: 'Annurca', color: 'red', size: '5', number: '50', scad: '2018'},
    {name: 'apple', cultivar: 'fuji', color: 'red', size: '4', number: '50', scad: 'NaN'}
];
```

Each element is complete with all the properties: *name*, *cultivar*, *color*, *size*, *number* and ***scad*** (which is `NaN` if the property doesn't exist).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging objects (associative arrays)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929776/merging-objects-associative-arrays)

Comment: Loop over one of them and call push on the other array for every object you encounter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `.map` the arrays together:

```js
var fruits = [
    {name: 'pear', cultivar: '', color: 'yellowgreen', size: '6'},
    {name: 'apple', cultivar: 'Annurca', color: 'red', size: '5'},
    {name: 'apple', cultivar: 'fuji', color: 'red', size: '4'}
]; 

var quantity = [
    {name: 'pear', number: '15'},
    {name: 'apple', number: '50', scad: '2018'},
    {name: 'apple', number: '50'}
];

const all = fruits.map((fruit, i) => (
  { ...fruit, scad: NaN, ...quantity[i] }
));
console.log(all);
```