# Combining 2+ 'deep' (multi-dimensional) hashes in perl

Tags: perl, hash, merge, hash-of-hashes

There is a question that explains exactly what I want here: [how to merge 2 deep hashes in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060331/how-to-merge-2-deep-hashes-in-perl)

**However**, the answer there does not seem to work for me (suggestions of using the `Merge` module).

I have two hashes like so:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '57494' => {
                       'name' => 'John Smith',
                       'age' => '9',
                       'height' => '120'
                     },
          '57495' => {
                       'name' => 'Amy Pond',
                       'age' => '17',
                       'height' => '168'
                     }
        }
};
$VAR1 = {
          '57494' => {
                       'name_address' => 'Peter Smith',
                       'address' => '5 Cambridge Road',
                       'post_code' => 'CR5 0FS'
                     }
        }
};
```

If I use `Hash::Merge` or the `%c = {%a,%b}` format I get this every time:

```
$VAR1 = '57494';
$VAR2 = {
          'name_address' => 'Peter Smith',
          'address' => '5 Cambridge Road',
          'post_code' => 'CR5 0FS'
        };
```

(so it basically overwrote the first data with the second and messed up the keys) when I want:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '57494' => {
                       'name' => 'John Smith',
                       'age' => '9',
                       'height' => '120'
                       'name_address' => 'Peter Smith',
                       'address' => '5 Cambridge Road',
                       'post_code' => 'CR5 0FS'
                     },
          '57495' => {
                       'name' => 'Amy Pond',
                       'age' => '17',
                       'height' => '168'
                     }
        }
};
```

So when the keys are the same, the data merges together, otherwise the new keys are just appended onto the end. I hope this make sense. Maybe I've done something incorrectly using `Merge` or need to 'manually' add them in loops, but I'm spending too much time thinking about it, regardless!

Edit: how I use Merge to see if I'm doing something silly:

I have:

```
use Hash::Merge qw( merge );

...hash data above as %hash1 and %hash2...

my %combined_hash = %{ merge( %hash1,%hash2 ) };
print Dumper(%combined_hash);
```

Comment: I don't. I get your desired result using either [**`Hash::Merge`**](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Hash::Merge) or [**`Hash::Merge::Simple`**](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Hash::Merge::Simple).

Comment: There are too many `}` in your example data...

Comment: If there are it is a copy and paste error. I copied from Dumper print out.

Comment: @Axeman if it worked for you, may I ask how you did it? It would be useful to know...

Comment: See my answer for what @Axeman probably did. I guess he just read the docs ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I do it with references, it works like a charm.

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Hash::Merge qw(merge);
my $h1 = {
  '57494' => {
    'name'   => 'John Smith',
    'age'    => '9',
    'height' => '120'
  },
  '57495' => {
    'name'   => 'Amy Pond',
    'age'    => '17',
    'height' => '168'
  }
};

my $h2 = {
  '57494' => {
    'name_address' => 'Peter Smith',
    'address'      => '5 Cambridge Road',
    'post_code'    => 'CR5 0FS'
  }
};

my $h3 = merge( $h1, $h2 );
print Dumper $h3;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
      '57495' => {
                   'name' => 'Amy Pond',
                   'age' => '17',
                   'height' => '168'
                 },
      '57494' => {
                   'name_address' => 'Peter Smith',
                   'name' => 'John Smith',
                   'post_code' => 'CR5 0FS',
                   'address' => '5 Cambridge Road',
                   'height' => '120',
                   'age' => '9'
                 }
    };
```

If, however, I do it with hashes instead of hash refs, it doesn't:

```
my %hash1 = (
  '57494' => {
    'name'   => 'John Smith',
    'age'    => '9',
    'height' => '120'
  },
  '57495' => {
    'name'   => 'Amy Pond',
    'age'    => '17',
    'height' => '168'
  }
);

my %hash2 = (
  '57494' => {
    'name_address' => 'Peter Smith',
    'address'      => '5 Cambridge Road',
    'post_code'    => 'CR5 0FS'
  }
);

my %h3 = merge( %hash1, %hash2 );
print Dumper \%h3;

__END__
$VAR1 = {
  '57495' => undef
};
```

That is because the `merge` from [Hash::Merge](https://metacpan.org/module/Hash::Merge) can only take references, but you are passing it hashes. In addition, you need to call it in **scalar context**.

Try it like so:

```
#                             +--------+--- references
#   ,-- SCALAR context        |        |
my $combined_hash = %{ merge( \%hash1, \%hash2 ) };
print Dumper($combined_hash);
```

Comment: ahh you know, I have my original versions as references but did this:
`my %h3 = %{ merge( $h1, $h2 )};` but when I changed it to pure references, it seems to work. Weird! 

I feel a little silly that I missed trying that combination, but thanks for making it clear to me!

Comment: @bladepanthera There was an error in it. The key (not the hash key) is to reference the two argument hashes, but to call it in scalar context. You need `$combined_hash`, not `%combined_hash`. Then you can reference the hashes you pass to `merge` and do not need to put them in reference variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
for my $key (keys %fromhash) {
    if(not exists $tohash{$key}) {
        $tohash{$key} = {};
    }
    for my $subkey (keys %{$fromhash{$key}}) {
        ${$tohash{$key}}{$subkey} = ${$fromhash{$key}}{$subkey};
    }
}
```

With more or less braces depending on whether my last coffee was any good.

Python is definitely more comfortable for this kind of thing, because it doesn't make you think about references:

```
for key in fromdict:
    if key not in todict:
        todict[key] = {}
    todict[key] = dict(fromdict[key].items() + todict[key].items())
```

Or if `todict` is a `defaultdict` (creating keys on read as well as assignment):

```
for key in fromdict:
    todict[key] = dict(dict(fromdict[key]).items() + dict(todict[key]).items())
```

Comment: I don't get the coffee reference.

Comment: Then you haven't had enough coffee either.

Comment: In fact there's one more brace required: `keys %{$fromhash{$key}})` in line 5. I'll stick to Yorkshire Tea though. =)

Comment: @Phil H, your perl code is working perfectly. But I am not able to understand the line no.3. My understanding is, it assigns an empty anonymous hash if the key is present in `%fromhash` and is absent in `%tohash`. But it is doing the correct thing by adding that key to `%tohash` and I am wrong. So could you please explain the logic on line no. 3. Thanks.

Comment: Without `$key` existing in `%tohash`, the assigment to that hash in the inner `for` loop would fail. So we create it if it is not defined by assigning it an empty hash reference.