# Hash merging method affected in Perl 5.18+ by hash order randomization?

Tags: perl, hash, merge

According to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350018/how-can-i-combine-hashes-in-perl), merging two hashes in Perl 5 can be done either with:

```
%newHash = (%hash1, %hash2); %hash1 = %newHash;
```

or:

```
@hash1{keys %hash2} = values %hash2;
```

On the other hand, [Perl 5.18 will introduce per process hash randomization](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1005122).

Will the second method still be correct to use in Perl 5.18?

Comment: BTW there's no need to use `%newHash` in the first example. You can just say `%hash1 = ( %hash1, %hash2 );`

Comment: Yeah I also thought of that. I just copied the examples from the answer to linked question, my main focus was the other example. Thanks  for the clarification though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After reading through [Re^2: Hash order randomization is coming, are you ready?](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1006246), the answer is **yes**. As before, `keys`, `values` and `each` will produce the same sequence iterating through the hash inside the *same process* if the hash isn't changed in between.

Comment: if anything it will be more likely to work as in perl's between 5.8.1 and 5.18 there was a small chance perl would rehash the hash with a random seed if it detected an attack. this would lead to the order changing. In 5.18 the seed remains constant for the life of the process

Comment: @user1937198 it's exactly as likely to work, because it always was (and still is) guaranteed that `keys` and `values` on the same hash return corresponding lists as long as the hash is not modified between the two calls.