# Perl - How to join 2 arrays/lists like [ a=>1, b=>2, ... ] to one?

Tags: arrays, perl, http-post, httprequest

I need to join 2 perl arrays/lists (sorry, do not know how they are named correctly) of format

```
[ a=>1, b=>2, c=>3 ] and [ d=>4, e=>5, f=6 ]
```

and need to join them to

```
[ a=>1, b=>2, c=>3, d=>4, e=>5, f=6 ]
```

How can I do this? I never used lists like this before...

I need it for HTTP::Request::Common

```
$ua->request(POST 'http://somewhere/foo', [foo => bar, bar => foo]);
```

because I have a set of standard parameters for every request and additionally custom parameters depending on the request. Of course I do not want to code the same stuff in every request but define the common parameters just once.

Tnx for your help,
Robert

### Clarification:

This is aprox. what I want to do:

```
my $result = httpPOST( $url, [ a=>1, b=2, ... ] );

sub httpPOST {
    my( $url, $params ) = @_; # ???
    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

    my $result  = $ua->request( POST $url, [ %auth, ????? ] );

    return $result->content;
}
```

Hmmm... I do not get the apropriate syntax. May you assist me one more time please!? ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350018/how-can-i-combine-hashes-in-perl

Comment: @squiguy, No hashes are involved here. That post deals with neither arrays nor references. Not a dupe of that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Perl, `=>` is called a "fat comma" and is basically the same as the normal `,`, except that you "don't need to quote words to the left of it". So basically

```
[ a=>1, b=>2, c=>3 ] and [ d=>4, e=>5, f=>6 ]
```

is identical to

```
[ 'a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3 ] and [ 'd', 4, 'e' 5, 'f', 6 ]
```

if you were wondering what the strange syntax did. In Perl, a common meme is to use things like `function(key => 'value')` in place of `function('key', 'value')` if it "looks more natural" to the writer. Perl itself does not mind either way.

You could merge these normally (`[ @$list1, @$list2 ]`), but in this case, it might not be what you want. You see, the reason `HTTP::Request::Common` uses arrays instead of regular hashes / hashrefs is that it needs to be able to define the same "key" with different "values". To quote from the module's perldoc:

> Multivalued form fields can be specified by either repeating the field name or by passing the value as an array reference.

So if you expect your "additional custom parameters" to override any "standard parameters" of the same name, this will not happen. To do this, you should treat them as actual hashes, and then force them to array refs:

```
my %standards = ( foo => 'bar', bar => 'foo');
my %additionals = ( foo => 'not-bar', this => 'that');
$ua->request(POST 'http://somewhere/foo', [ %standards, %additionals ]);
```

Comment: Tnx. See my additional details below.

Answer (score 6):

```
[ ... ]
```

is similar to

```
do { my @anon = ( ... ); \@anon }
```

You have a hash (`%auth`) and a reference to an array (`$params`).

---

`%hash` gets the elements of a hash as a list of keys and values.

`@array` gets the elements of an array, which means that `@$ref` gets the elements of a referenced array.

All you need is

```
 [ %auth, @$params ]
```

---

Note that you should never use `->content`. Use `->decoded_content` instead. You should thus use the following code:

```
my $response  = $ua->request( POST $url, [ %auth, @$params ] );
return $response->decoded_content( charset => 'none' );
```

(`charset => 'none'` works around a bug that breaks XML responses.)