# Add multiple values to an already existing hash

Tags: perl, hash

I have the following hash, and I want to add more values to it; however, doing it replaces the entire hash. I'm pretty sure this is a basic level question, but perl is an enigma wrapped in a mystery.

```
my %myNewHash = ();

%myNewHash = (
    lastName => $primaryInfo->{lastName},
    firstName => $primaryInfo->{firstName}
);

%myNewHash = (
    email => $primaryInfo->{email},
    phone => $primaryInfo->{phone}
);
```

At this point, `%myNewHash` only contains email/phone, lastName/firstName have been wiped out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350018/how-can-i-combine-hashes-in-perl/350038#350038

Comment: When you say `$foo = 1;` followed by `$foo = 2;`, what is the value of `$foo`? Hashes work the same way.

Comment: I know it's fashionable to bash Perl but it helps no one. All the languages that I can think of that have built-in hash support behave in the same way - assign to the hash as a whole and you change the contents as a whole - and I can't see a better way. If you had it your way then `%myNewHash = ()` would leave the hash untouched, so how could you empty it?

Comment: At the command prompt type the following: `perldoc perlintro`.  It's about a 20 minute read, and will unwrap the mystery leaving you only with the enigma... ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Existing hash (note that you don't need create an empty hash before assigning to it):

```
my %myNewHash = (
    lastName => $primaryInfo->{lastName},
    firstName => $primaryInfo->{firstName}
);
```

Since you're using the same keys in the new and the old hashes:

```
$myNewHash{$_} = $primaryInfo->{$_} for qw(email phone);
```

Or with a hash slice:

```
my @keys = qw(email phone);
@myNewHash{@keys} = @{ $primaryInfo }{@keys};
```

The key (pun intended) is that you assign to an individual element

```
$hash{key} = ...
```

instead of to the hash itself

```
%hash = ( ... );
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way you can do it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %myNewHash = (
    lastName  => $primaryInfo->{lastName},
    firstName => $primaryInfo->{firstName}
);

$myNewHash{email} =  $primaryInfo->{email};
$myNewHash{phone} =  $primaryInfo->{phone};
```

Or:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %myNewHash;
$myNewHash{lastName}  =  $primaryInfo->{lastName};
$myNewHash{firstName} =  $primaryInfo->{firstName}
$myNewHash{email}     =  $primaryInfo->{email};
$myNewHash{phone}     =  $primaryInfo->{phone};
```

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you do:

```
%myNewHash = ...;
```

You're reinitializing the value of %myNewHash. This is what the `=` operator does. It's the same thing as:

```
my $var = "This is the first part of my sentence,";
my $var = " and this is the last part of my sentence."; # Reinitializing $var, not appending it
```

To get around this, you could do the following:

```
%myNewHash = ( %myNewHash, email => $primaryInfo->{email}, phone => $primaryInfo->{phone} );
```

In this context, the key/value pairs in `%myNewHash` are treated as an array, The other two key/value pairs are put into that array and assigned to `%myNewHash` as one big array. `%myNewHash` is reinitialized, but now contains the exiting key/value pairs it had before.

I personally wouldn't do this because it's not 100% clear what's going on. If you want to convert your hash reference into a hash, you can dereference it and do it all in a single shot:

```
my %myNewHash = %{ $primaryInfo };  # Easy to understand.
```

Or use a loop to pick off the few keys you want to transfer over:

```
for my $key ( qw( email phone ) } {
    $myNewHash{$key} = $primaryInfo->{$key};
}
```

I'm sure there's even a way to use [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html), but I can't think of it right off hand.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding like this:

```
%myNewHash = (
    %myNewHash,
    email => $primaryInfo->{email},
    phone => $primaryInfo->{phone}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this by "slicing" the hash.
Put the sigil @ in front of the hash name (which indicates that you use a slice of the hash), provide the new keys within curly braces (which indicates you are referring to a hash and to its single entries) and then just assign the values for the new entries

```
@myNewHash{"email", "phone"} = ("name@domain.tld", "+122222222222");
```