# Unable to properly merge hashes

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I currently have the following

```
# $dog, $cat, $rat are all hash refs

                my %rethash = ('success' => 'Your Cool'); 

                my %ref ={ 'dog' => $dog,  'cat' => $cat,  'mouse' => $rat,
                                'chicken' => ''  };

                my $perlobj = ( \%ref,\%rethash );
```

When $perlobj is dumped this is the result

```
 $VAR1 = {
      'success' => 'Your Cool'
    };
```

However when warnings are enabled I get the following message

```
Useless use of reference constructor in void context at ..
```

I realize there is something terribly wrong with how %ref is assigned using {}, What is wrong with this code? I can't seem to get rid of this warning....

EDIT:
Ok I think I figured out whats going on,

```
my $perlobj = ( \%ref,\%rethash );
```

This does not merge but results in $perlobj becoming a reference to %rethash, this is obvious after reading your responses.

Comment: You're use `{}` when creating `%ref` when you should be using `()`

Comment: You also want `my %perlobj = ( %ref,%rethash );`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I combine hashes in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350018/how-can-i-combine-hashes-in-perl)

Comment: You are wildly mixing `()` parens and `{}` as well as hashes and hash-references. And you have found a rare instance of `,` as a sequence operator instead of a list constructor.

Comment: @PatrickJ.S. could you elaborate on the sequence operator? I cannot find that in perldoc.

Comment: @simbabque: In the docs it's just called ["comma" operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator). I was reffering to [this usage of _sequence_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator#Syntax). Admittedly the expresseion "as a sequence operator" is a bit sloppy and could have better been said with “used the `,`-operator for sequencing”,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What RobEarl is saying is correct. I'll give an explanation of that and add some more stuff.

Your variable name `%ref` and the fact that you are using `{}` kinda implies you want a reference here.

Let's take a look what value we will have in `%ref`. Consider this example.

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Printer;
my %foo = { key => 'value' };
p %foo;
```

This will throw a warning *Reference found where even-sized list expected* on my Perl 5.20.2. The output will be:

```
{
    HASH(0x7e33c0)   undef
}
```

It's a hash with a hashref as the key and `undef` as a value. `HASH(0x07e33c0)` is what you get when you look at a hash reference without dereferencing it. (The `{}` are there because Data::Printer converts the hash to a hashref).

Back to your code, the correct sigil for a reference is `$`. It does not matter what kind of reference it is. The reference is always a scalar (a pointer to the place in memory where the hash/array/something) is stored.

```
my $ref = { 
  dog     => $dog,
  cat     => $cat,
  mouse   => $rat,
  chicken => '', # maybe this should be undef?
};
```

Now you've got a hashref with the values of `$dog`, `$cat`, `$rat` and an empty string.

Now you're assigning a variable named `$perlobj`, which implies it's an object. Instead you are assigning a scalar variable (the `$` makes it a scalar) with a list. If you do that, Perl will only assign the right-most value to the variable.

```
my $foo = (1, 2, 3); # $foo will be 3 and there's a warning
```

You are assigning a list of two references. The first one is disregarded and only `\$rethash` gets assigned. That works because conveniently, `$perlobj` is a scalar, and references are also scalars. So now `$perlobj` is a reference of `%rethash`. That's why your Data::Dumper output looks like `%rethash`.

---

I'm not sure what you want to do, so I cannot really help you with that. I suggest you read up on some stuff.

- [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) is useful to learn how references work
- If you want to do Object Oriented Programming, check out [Moose](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose)
- It might also be useful to just go get a book to learn a bit more about basic Perl. *Learning Perl* by Randal L. Schwartz and *Beginning Perl* by Curtis Poe are both very good for that

Comment: Thanks for breaking it down I really appreciate it, I was going through some old code and added warnings to a module and found this error.

Answer (score 2):

You are taking a list of hash references and assigning them to a scalar

```
my $perlobj = ( \%ref, \%rethash );  # same as  $perlobj = \%rethash
```

Instead you want to take a reference to a merger of hashes

```
my $perlobj = { %ref, %rethash };
```