# Perl - Merge hash containing duplicate keys

Tags: perl, hash

I have two hashes which can contain the same keys. I am trying to merge the two hashes in such a way that if the key exists in both the hashes, I want to add the values in the respective hashes.

```
my %hash1= ();
$hash1{'apple'} = 10;
$hash1{'banana'} = 15;
$hash1{'kiwi'} = 20;

my %sourceHash = ();
$sourceHash{'apple'} = 12;
$sourceHash{'orange'} = 13;
$sourceHash{'banana'} = 5;


mergeHash(\%hash1, \%sourceHash);


sub mergeHash {
    my $hash1 = shift;
    my $hash2 = shift;

    foreach my $key (keys %{$hash1})
    {
        if (exists $hash2->{$key}) {
            ${hash2}->{$key} = $hash1->{$key} + $hash2->{$key};
        } else {
            ${hash2}->{$key} = $hash1->{$key};
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the result of hash1 to be

```
hash1{'apple'} = 22;
hash1{'orange'} = 13;
hash1{'banana'} = 20;
hash1{'kiwi'} = 20;
```

But I get an exception saying Can't modify constant item in scalar assignment. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The program runs fine for me.

Comment: What you posted doesn't demonstrate the problem you claim it does. Please fix your question. [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PFB the updated code with proper syntax and it is giving the desired output also:

```
my %hash1= ();
$hash1{'apple'} = 10;
$hash1{'banana'} = 15;
$hash1{'kiwi'} = 20;

my %sourceHash = ();
$sourceHash{'apple'} = 12;
$sourceHash{'orange'} = 13;
$sourceHash{'banana'} = 5;

mergeHash(\%hash1, \%sourceHash);


sub mergeHash {
    my $param1 = shift;
    my %hash1 = %$param1;
    my $param2 = shift;
    my %hash2 = %$param2;

    foreach my $key (keys %hash1){
        if(exists $hash2{$key}){
            print "coming in here for $hash1->{$key} \n";
            $hash2{$key} = $hash1{$key} + $hash2{$key};
        }
        else{
            $hash2{$key} = $hash1{$key};
        }
    }
    showHash(\%hash2);
}
sub showHash{

    my $param = shift;
    my %param_hash = %$param;


    for my $fruit (keys %param_hash) {
    print "The value of '$fruit' is $param_hash{$fruit}\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Weirdly, my local box was throwing me errors. I'll try updating my perl version just in case.

Comment: Try running this code i pasted to confirm that it's your perl version that is creating issues. You could also try running in https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_perl_online.php

Comment: As your code was not giving desired output for me also

Comment: Your code now gives me the desired results. Was there something I was missing?

Comment: I hope issue was in this line-  $hash2->{$accountId} where does accountid come from

Comment: also the way of receiving params, you need to change them to hash

Comment: Ah I see, I was under the assumption I can use the hashrefs the way they are and wasn't completely required to change them to a hash.

Comment: *also the way of receiving params, you need to change them to hash* - No. He doesn't need to change that. Using hash references is a perfectly reasonable way to write this code.

Comment: @chrisrhyno2003: *I was under the assumption I can use the hashrefs the way they are and wasn't completely required to change them to a hash." - You are correct. Your original code was fine.

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> I  expect the result of hash1 to be
>
> ```
> hash1{'apple'} = 22;
> hash1{'orange'} = 13;
> hash1{'banana'} = 20;
> hash1{'kiwi'} = 20;
> ```

But in your code, you iterate over the keys of `$hash1`:

> ```
>  foreach my $key (keys %{$hash1})
> ```

And alter the contents of `$hash2`:

> ```
> if (exists $hash2->{$key}) {
>     ${hash2}->{$key} = $hash1->{$key} + $hash2->{$key};
> } else {
>     ${hash2}->{$key} = $hash1->{$key};
> }
> ```

So you shouldn't expect to see any changes in `$hash1`, you are changing `$hash2`.

I added this to your code:

```
use Data::Dumper;
```

And, after the call to `mergeHash()`:

```
print Dumper \%hash1, \%sourceHash;
```

I got this output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'apple' => 10,
          'kiwi' => 20,
          'banana' => 15
        };
$VAR2 = {
          'orange' => 13,
          'banana' => 20,
          'kiwi' => 20,
          'apple' => 22
        };
```

So your code is doing what you wanted. It's just doing it to the other hash. There's nothing wrong with your code.